# Development kits for OPAL SSC full-disk encryption

Tags: encryption, hard-drive

I am looking for development kits or utilities to interact with and test [OPAL SSC](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/storage_work_group_storage_security_subsystem_class_opal) full disk encryption. I could get it working from BIOS, but that makes R&D tricky. Please pass along any helpful tips or utilities.

The question would be answered if consensus emerges that there are no such utilities readily available or one is pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

**[ULINK DriveMaster 2010](http://www.ulinktech.com/products.asp)** supports TCG Opal and Enterprise protocols for both SATA and SCSI interfaces. It provides set of function to generate payload with encoded tokens stream for IF-SEND command and parse response from IF-RECV call in handy format. Payload buffer can also be updated manually to simulate encoding errors.

What is more, ULINK provides complete [test suit](http://www.ulinktech.com/product_tcg.asp) for [TCG Storage Workgroup OPAL Test Cases](http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/tcg_storage_opal_test_cases).